# Spring framework REST multivalue request parameter empty array

Tags: java, spring, rest, param, multivalue

I have a rest endpoint (spring-boot-1.3.0-RELEASE -> spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE) which takes a multiple instance string parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getTest(@RequestParam(value = "testParam", required = false) String[] testParamArray) {}

/test?testParam=  => testParamArray has length 0
/test?testParam=&testParam=  => testParamArray has length 2 (two empty string items)
```

I expected that for the first case to get a single empty sting element in the array but there are none.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Check if your browser or http client is not discarding the empty param.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. When using something like @RequestParam Map<String, String> params, I see the single null value in there (?testParam=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring's `StringToArrayConverter` is responsible for this conversion. If you take a look at its `convert` method:

```
public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String string = (String) source;
        String[] fields = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(string);
        Object target = Array.newInstance(targetType.getElementTypeDescriptor().getType(), fields.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            String sourceElement = fields[i];
            Object targetElement = this.conversionService.convert(sourceElement.trim(), sourceType, targetType.getElementTypeDescriptor());
            Array.set(target, i, targetElement);
        }
        return target;
}
```

Basically, it takes the input (empty `String` in your case), split it by **comma** and return an array with values of the exploded `String`. Result of splitting an empty `String`, of course, is an empty `Array`.

When you pass two parameters with the same name, the `ArrayToArrayConverter` will be called, which behaves as you would expect and returns an array with two empty `String`s.

If you want to disable the default `String` to `Array` behavior, you should register another `Converter` that converts an empty `String` to a single element `Array`.

Comment: Thank you, Ali. I understand the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ali's correct answer...

You can register a `Converter` that directs Spring to treat the empty string as an array with the empty string within the `addFormatters` method of your `WebMvcConfigurer` bean.

```
@Configuration
public class MyMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        // Register a converter so that an empty string web parameter,
        // when converted to a String[], is treated as an array with
        // one element (the empty string), instead of an empty array.
        registry.addConverter(new Converter<String, String[]>() {
            @Override
            public String[] convert(String source) {
                if (source.isEmpty()) { // Special case empty string
                    return new String[] { "" };
                }

                return StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(source);
            }
        });
    }
}
```